# ASP.Net MVC routing doesn't like parameter value of CON

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

If I simply generate an MVC Web App with VS2013. Then the only code change I make is to change the Contact action to accept the string param.

```
public ActionResult Contact(string id)
```

If I call it with http://localhost:55213/Home/Contact/CONN
the parameter comes through fine.
If I call it with http://localhost:55213/Home/Contact/CON
I get a 404.

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:55213/Home/Contact?id=CON

Comment: Are you using a route config or any routing attributes?

Comment: Yes as a query string it works.

Comment: Out of the box vanilla VS generated app. public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: Is this because of CON like stdout?

Comment: Intellitrace is saying: System.Web.HttpException failed to map /home/contact/con

Comment: Funny, no forbidden filenames are allowed: CON PRN AUX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil Haack documents the issue:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

[Phil Haack's Post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/)